# Maximum of a mollified/convolution function

Tags: approximation-theory, global-optimization, convolution

I have a function $f:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow {\mathbb R}_+$ which has a unique maximum at $x=0$. $f$ can be symmetric or asymmetric. I am interested on the mollified-f function

$$\tilde{f}(x)=\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\varphi(y)f(x-y)dy,\,\,\, \epsilon>0$$

I wonder if there are general results on the [Mollifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) $\varphi$, such that $\tilde{f}$ also has a unique maximum (not necessarily at $0$).

Comment: Questions like this have been treated in the concept of "scale space methods" in mathematical image processing about 15 or 20 years ago where one was interested in the question: How many local minima and maxima survive after convolution and can new local minima or maxima be created? Unfortunately I forgot about the exact references but one result was along the lines: If you take a scale kernel $\phi_t(x) = 1/t\phi(x/t)$ and require that the number of local maxima and minima of $\phi_t\ast f$ is decaying with $t$, and some more hypotheses, then $\phi$ is a Gaussian…

Comment: @Dirk Many thanks for the helpful pointer.

Comment: It is easy to see that any condition on the mollifier is not sufficient. You need some conditions on $f$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my comment extended into an answer. In scale space theory one considers a family of mollifiers $\phi(x,t)$ where $t$ is a positive scale parameter. Under a number of axioms (see [scale-space axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-space_axioms)), one of which is "non-creation of local extrema of $\phi(\cdot,t)\ast f$ if $t$ increases"  and another is the semi-group property $\phi(\cdot,t)\ast\phi(\cdot,s) = \phi(\cdot,s+t)$, one can conclude that $\phi(x,t)$ has to be a Gaussian with variance $\sqrt{t}$. If one discards some axioms one obtains more possible functions. References are the classical ["The structure of images"](http://image.diku.dk/imagecanon/material/Koenderink84.pdf) by Koenderink from 1984 or a paper by Weickert et al. on an older appearance of this concept (1959 by Iijima): ["Linear scale space have first been proposed in Japan"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1008344623873) from 1999.